# Module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot' in pycord version 2.3.2

Tags: discord, bots, pycord

I'm trying to switch from discord.py to pycord since I heard that they don't support slash commands, and while defining simple commands. I keep getting this great Traceback
`

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\****\source\repos\DBot\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot = discord.Bot()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'
```

`

This is my code up until now.
`

```py
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# importing environmental vars
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")
APP_ID = os.getenv("APP_ID")
PUB_KEY = os.getenv("PUBLIC_KEY")
GUILD_ID = os.getenv("GUILD_ID")
GENERAL_CHAN_ID = os.getenv("CHANNEL_GENERAL_ID")
#finished importing .env vars

#class for client
bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.slash_command()
async def hello(ctx, name: str = None):
    name = name or ctx.author.name
    await ctx.respond(f"Hello {name}!")

@bot.user_command(name="Say Hello")
async def hi(ctx, user):
    await ctx.respond(f"{ctx.author.mention} says hello to {user.name}!")

bot.run("token")
```

`

I have py-cord version 2.3.2 so I know it's not version issue
I just started using py-cord so I have no idea what I'm doing except ctrl c ctrl v-ing examples from their documentation page to see if it works

Help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake.

What fixed it for me was:

1. Go into your project directory.
2. pip install py-cord if this doesn't work, try step 3.
3. pip install py-cord==2.0.0rc1 this is a beta version of pycord.